# How to concat text class with Vuejs 2

Tags: vuejs2

How do I dynamically concat a text with vuejs 2

Here is what I have now:

```
<span class="label" :class="label-{{account.Segment}}">{{account.Segment}}</span>
```

account.Segment == "ABC"

What I need rendered is that

```
<span class="label label-ABC">ABC</span>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one possible way.

```
<span class="label" :class="'label-' + account.Segment">{{account.Segment}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more classes using an array of string

```
computed: {
  classNames() {
    // add more logic here
    let classNames = ['label'];
    classNames.push(`label-${this.contextType}`);
    return classNames;
  },
},
```

and then you can use it like this

```
<div :class="classNames">
...
</div>
```